# What are the benefits of using Laravel Request Class in API's development?

Tags: laravel, api

Is there any benefit of using laravel requests classes for **store** and **update**  methods in developing restful API's? Or do I have to make custom **Validator::make** response?

I have been facing difficulty in modifying the response format from failed requests as to follow some development standards requirements.

Can we modify the failed responses format from request class for API's?

Comment: Can you show us few lines of code you tried

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use **independent** from request class because there is at least one benefit: more clear code.

you can generate response as you wish like this (this is my solution, maybe there are more better solutions. i use this solution to return only one validation error not all. you can modify it as you wish):

in your Form request class add this method:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;

        foreach ($validator->messages()->getMessages() as $key => $value) {
            $first_messages_only[$key]  = $value[0];
        }

        throw new ValidationException($first_messages_only);
    }
```

and then in your Exception handler class, write this block of code in your **render()** method:

```
if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
            $response = [
                'status' => false,
                'message' => trans('api.general.validation_not_passed'), // $exception->getMessage()
                'data' => ['validation_errors' => $exception->validator]
            ];
            return response()->json($response);

        }
```

Comment: Yes, this does serves my purpose of modifying my response format. I would like to wait for more examples until I mark it as my desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked its usage in API development then you can easily tell request class that you want json response by adding **application/json** header in your request then it will return json response.

Request class is best approach to validate incoming input from user which provides a lot of other features as well.

In Request class you can write validation rules for all request types e.g. get,post,put|patch or delete

You can allow or disallow anyone using authorize method based on your project logic.

You can write custom messages and send them custom error message bags.

If you write whole thing in a controller method then that will not be a good approach and difficult to manage while request class will make you comfortable while dealing with validations only.

```
protected $errorBag = 'custom_errors_bag'

public function authorize()
{
    return true;  //or any other logic here to authorize the user
}

public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()){
        case  'POST':
            return [
                'username' => 'required|string|max:20|unique:users',
                //...
            ];
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
            return [
                'username' => 'required|string|max:20|unique:users,id',
                //...
            ];
        case 'DELETE':[
                'id' => 'required'
               //...
            ];
        default:break;
    }
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'username.required' => 'Please provide username',
        'username.unique' => 'Username must be unique',
        //...
    ];
}
```

Comment: Yes I do have the understanding of the same. But in my case my response format is not what the above code will return. It will simply return the response as per the message format you provide in the message function and finally it will return with error['key'=>'value'] format. What if you have more data to return on a logical basis. There is quite less flexibility in this way of response. Or can you redefine the message format here in the message function. Please note that the format flexibility is also a requirement.

Comment: Got you. you can use failedValidation() method to format response as you like.